# Trying to turn a GRID Stack 7.x to GeoTIFF

Tags: arcmap, geotiff-tiff, global-mapper

I have a set of imagery that contains the following folders:

```
aerial
aerialc1
aerialc2
aerialc3
info
```

When I load the folder (or folders) into ArcMap, they all display perfectly. When I try and export to GeoTIFF, the resulting imagery is always black and unusable. I've tried Project Raster as well since I wanted to change the projection type. Nothings seems to be working. I also attempted to load the folders into Global Mapper, but that didn't work either.

I just need to get the imagery into a GeoTIFF format. Its about 770 GB in total.

Comment: You probably just need to build statistics; the default range is that of the datatype, so higher pixel bits will result in a wider possible range, and lower values will darken.

Comment: @Vince Thank you, I will try that and update you with the results.

Comment: @Vince Hello Vince. So I built statistics on the imagery after I converted it to a geotiff. Now it shows up properly in the tiler program I use (world wind tiler).

Problem is, now I get a weird error that doesn't allow the imagery to tile. I'll try something else real quick and then come back if it doesn't work. 

That said, what you said was very helpful. Thank you!